Salesforce Login chrome extension issue
I've been trying to create a chrome extension for Managing Salesforce Org credential,where the tool can save and login multiple salesforce org credentials. I've been seeking ChatGPT for the JavaScript functions.while testing my package i've been able to save the creds and the login button just takes me to the salesforce Log in page, i would like it to automate the login functionality by passing the values from my extension page. my debug scripts are not coming up in the console to.where could i have gone wrong here?
The console log says the following error

clientlibs_www_tags.min.js:2
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

popup.js
function autoLogin(username, password, orgType) {
  const loginUrl = orgType === 'sandbox' ? 'https://test.salesforce.com/' : 'https://login.salesforce.com/';

  chrome.tabs.create({ url: loginUrl }, function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function listener(tabId, changeInfo) {
      if (tabId === tab.id && changeInfo.status === 'complete') {
        chrome.tabs.onUpdated.removeListener(listener);

        chrome.scripting.executeScript({
          target: { tabId: tab.id },
          func: (username, password) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
              const usernameField = document.querySelector('input[name="username"]');
              const passwordField = document.querySelector('input[name="pw"]');
              const loginButton = document.querySelector('#Login');

              if (usernameField && passwordField && loginButton) {
                usernameField.value = username;
                passwordField.value = password;

                // Debugging output
                console.log('Username filled:', usernameField.value);
                console.log('Password filled:', passwordField.value);
                
                // Optional alert for debugging
                alert(`Username: ${usernameField.value}, Password: ${passwordField.value}`);

                loginButton.click();
              } else {
                console.error('Login fields not found on the page.');
              }
            }, 6000); // Adjust timeout as needed
          },
          args: [username, password]
        });
      }
    });
  });
}

